# Why is $\langle \hat{J}_x \rangle=\langle \hat{J}_y \rangle=0$ if we have a state invariant under rotations about the $z$-axis?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, angular-momentum, operators, hilbert-space, symmetry

In Leslie E Balletine chapter 8 they state that for a state $\rho=|jm\rangle \langle jm|$ that is an eigenstate of $\mathbf{J}^2$ and $J_z$ we have that $\langle J_x\rangle=\langle J_y\rangle=0$ and $\langle J_x^2\rangle=\langle J_y^2\rangle$
How do you prove this? What are the physical implications?

Comment: Because $0$ is the only vector in the plane $x,y$ invariant under rotations around $z$.

Answer (score 2):

Here's another sweet way of seeing $\langle L_x\rangle=\langle L_y\rangle=0$: use the uncertainty relations for angular momentum operators:
\begin{align}
\Delta L_x \Delta L_z &\ge \frac{1}{2}\vert\langle L_y\rangle\vert^2 \, , \tag{1}\\
\Delta L_y \Delta L_z &\ge \frac{1}{2}\vert\langle L_x\rangle\vert^2 \, . \tag{2}
\end{align}
Since your state is an eigenstate of $L_z$, then $\Delta L_z=0$ which implies the rhs of (1) and (2) must also be $0$.

Answer (score 0):

The ladder operator relations read
$$
L_x = \frac{1}{2} (L_+ + L_-) \\
L_y = \frac{1}{2i} (L_+ - L_-) 
$$

We then have

\begin{align}
\require{cancel}
\langle j,m | L_x | jm \rangle &= \frac{1}{2}  \langle j,m | L_+ | j,m \rangle + \frac{1}{2} \langle j,m | L_- | j,m \rangle  = \frac{1}{2} \cancel{\langle j,m | j,m+1 \rangle} + \frac{1}{2} \cancel{\langle j,m | j,m-1 \rangle}\\
& = 0
\end{align}

The $L_y$ case is analogous. Now squaring the operators
$$
L_x^2 = \frac{1}{4} (L_+^2 + L_-^2 + L_+L_- + L_-L_+) \\
L_y^2 = -\frac{1}{4} (L_+^2 + L_-^2 - L_+L_-  - L_-L_+) 
$$

But, similarly to before, for a $|j,m\rangle$ state $\langle L_\pm^2 \rangle = 0$ and therefore $\langle L_x^2 \rangle = \langle L_y^2 \rangle = \frac{1}{4} \langle L_+L_- + L_-L_+ \rangle $ .

Because $| j,m \rangle$ states are invariant under $z$ rotations, the $x$ and $y$ axis must be indistinguishable. It follows that $\langle J_x \rangle = \langle J_y \rangle$;  $\langle J_x^2 \rangle = \langle J_y^2 \rangle$. Also, as Valter pointed out, classically  $\vec{L}$ must have zero component lying in the $x,y$ plane, which leads to $\langle J_{x} \rangle = \langle J_{y} \rangle = 0$.